# C# - Windows Universal app - Image Source doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm trying to define source for my image in Windows Universal app, but it givs me following error:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

```
imagePath = "Assets/Category-other-dark.png";
Uri uri = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
imgCategory.Source = imgSource;
```

I search through many forums and tryed a lot of things but nothing works. Thank you.

Comment: I tried what's written in that article.

Comment: Where is your png location? App package or App data?

Answer (score 7):

Change it to:

```
imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/Category-other-dark.png";
Uri uri = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
imgCategory.Source = imgSource;
```

Comment: I tried it, but... 'The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri.'

Comment: BTW: What's the difference between `ms-appx` and `ms-appdata`?

Answer (score 0):

You must use local, roaming or temp:

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appdata:///local/Assets/logo.png");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    imagePath = "Assets/Category-other-dark.png";
    Uri uri = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
    imgCategory.Source = imgSource;
```

Comment: I tried it, but... 'The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri.'

Comment: While importing check your imported package name. Import System.Uri instead of Windows.Foundation.Uri

Comment: While importing of what? I don't understand. Excuse my knowledge and bad English. :)